# Run rake db:drop without failure if database doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, rake, rake-task

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129452/how-to-know-if-db-exists-from-within-rake-task#comment8545989_7129452) says:

> db:drop can run without failure when db does not exist

This is exactly what I need: I need to run db:drop but without throwing an exception or halt my whole process if the database doesn't exist, just delete the database if it exists or do  nothing.

How can I do that? how can I tell `db:drop` not to destroy my life if the database doesn't exist?

This is the code I'm experiencing the problem with (it it help):

```
namespace :db do
  task import: :environment do
    Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke # If the database doesn't already exist, the whole import process terminates!
    Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
    database_config = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    system "psql --username=#{database_config['username']} #{database_config['database']} < PostgreSQL.sql"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you go for simple exception handling

```
namespace :db do
  task import: :environment do
    begin
      Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke # If the database doesn't already exist, the whole import process terminates!
      Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
      database_config = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
      system "psql --username=#{database_config['username']} #{database_config['database']} < PostgreSQL.sql"
   rescue Exception => e
     p "The Exception is #{e.message}"
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Surely the OP wants the rest of the process (ie. the db:create onwards) to execute if the db:drop fails. In this code, it will skip that code and goto the exception block.