# Rake task dependent if database already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Just to preface that I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129452/how-to-know-if-db-exists-from-within-rake-task) and others but no answer really mentions a way to do it in a rake task.

I want to do a setup script that somewhat looks like this:

```
  if database_exists?
    sh 'rake db:migrate'
  else
    sh 'rake db:setup'
  end
```

I haven't written `database_exists?` but how can I tell if the users system has this database already created?

I don't want to run `rake db:setup` every time which will drop the users database. 
I suppose I could run `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` each time but then the user would need to run `rake db:seed` in addition to the rake task which right now is part of the `db:setup` process.

Comment: This is a pointless test. Just use `rake db:setup`. It won't *recreate* the database if it already exists. You can run it as many times as you like with no negative effects after the database is created and migrations are run.

Comment: @meagar- db:setup runs `db:create, db:schema:load, db:seed` - won't this seed everytime they run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to write a ruby script to run with `rails runner` or a rake task, where you can define your database_exists? method like this:

```
def database_exists?
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection
rescue ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
  false
else
  true
end
```

**Documentation**

- [ActiveRecord::Base.connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-connection)
- [ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NoDatabaseError.html)